# CAMl query to get all the listitems whose ID value in between 100 and 110 in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, caml-query

I need to get the list items from SP 2010 SPList,  having the below criteria:

get all the records/listitems whose ID value in between 100 and 110. 
What should be the CAMl query for matching the above criteria.i have tried the below , but unfortunately it didn't work. i dont have U2U2 CAML builder tool installed in my dev machine.Hence, i am not able to test this!

```
        <Query>
         <Where>
          <And>
            <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Number'>100</Value>
           </Gt>
           <Lt>
             <FieldRef Name='ID' />
           <Value Type='Number'>110</Value>
      </Lt>
       </And>
     </Where>
  </Query>
```

Comment: if you are using SSOM, you need to get rid of `<Query>` tags

Comment: am using SPServices Lib, camlqueryoptions  attribute, camlviewfields . and not using SSOM..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `Geq` and `Leq` to be inclusive. Since you are using the ID column the type is actually `Counter`.

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <Value Type='Counter'>100</Value>
      </Geq>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <Value Type='Counter'>110</Value>
      </Leq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: i will try and revert here!

Comment: Is it possible to get the numbers using IN operator , what i see is,  after applying the above counter using geq and leq,  some items were missing from the list.

Comment: Do the items actually exist? If you are using foldering, the default is to only pull items at the root level so you'll have to use the `RecursiveAll` scope to get nested items. The `in` operator requires you provide the values (which would work, but a range makes a lot more sense for finding all values between values)